# Spring Security bcrypt constructor

Tags: constructor, spring-security, bcrypt

I have a question about the implementation of the bcrypt in spring security.The class "org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" In the first constructor of the bcrypt i see "this(-1);" what does this exactly mean. As far as i understand this should refer to the field "strength" and the default value should be 10 set in org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt "private static final int GENSALT_DEFAULT_LOG2_ROUNDS = 10;", but then what is -1 referring to, to the first constructor?

```
public class BCryptPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {
    private Pattern BCRYPT_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\A\\$2a?\\$\\d\\d\\$[./0-9A-Za-z]{53}");
    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    private final int strength;

    private final SecureRandom random;

    public BCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        this(-1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you got that far, why not just look at [where it's used in remainder of the file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java#L64)?

Unless the value is greater than zero, it just calls the default JBCrypt `genSalt` function:

```
BCrypt.gensalt();
```

which in turn [uses the default strength setting](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java#L758).

Comment: ups that was a little bit embarrassing. Thank you for the reply, next time i will think twice before asking such questions.